# Cucumber/Capybara test no longer run in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

Do the latest versions of these gems not work with each other any more? It appears that something may have gotten out of whack in my bundle.

```
undefined local variable or method `node' for #<Capybara::Driver::RackTest::Node:0x103e19390> (NameError)
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:35
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/signing_in.feature:11:in `And I follow "Login"'
```

All I am trying to do is run a feature with:

```
bundle exec cucumber features/signing_in.feature
```

I can't run any tests.

```
capybara-0.4.0
cucumber-rails-0.3.2
cucumber-0.9.2
```

I did re-run the install script for cucumber. Let me also add that I have no idea what is attempting to call "Node" inside of Capybara::Drive::RackTest.

Comment: "No longer"? What did you change?

Comment: I upgraded the gems. See answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"...problem... cucumber monkey-patches a Capybara method which no longer exists...comment out 'cucumber/capybara-javascript-emulation'... the error will go away"

$ features/support/env.rb

HAPPY CODING!!

http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/issue/87/#issue/87/comment/433959

Comment: That comment seems to be gone, but the general link still works: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/87